# Need help fixing a non-obvious error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making a basic calculator for my website and I keep getting an error message and I don't know why.

I have 3 input boxes, all with the same style. The code basically validates the input so that it can only be a number. If text or other characters it'll change the border colour of the respected box and display an error message:

```js
function validateInput() {
  validateArea = document.getElementById("area").value;
  validateLength = document.getElementById("length").value;
  validateWidth = document.getElementById("width").value;
  if (isNaN(validateArea)) {
    area.style.border = "solid 2px red";
    areaInvalid.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    area.style.border = "solid 2px black";
    areaInvalid.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  if (isNaN(validateLength)) {
    length.style.border = "solid 2px red"; //broken
    lengthInvalid.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    length.style.border = "solid 2px black"; //broken
    lengthInvalid.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  if (isNaN(validateWidth)) {
    width.style.border = "solid 2px red";
    widthInvalid.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    width.style.border = "solid 2px black";
    widthInvalid.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
.inputCalc {
  width: 60%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="area" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="Area (m²)" autocomplete="off" onclick="areaUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()">
<input id="length" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="Length" autocomplete="off" onclick="lxbUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()">
<input id="width" class="inputCalc" type="text" placeholder="Width" autocomplete="off" onclick="lxbUpdated()" onchange="validateInput()">
```

Somehow, the two lines commented with "broken" display the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'border' of undefined" whilst the other two boxes work perfectly fine. If you need anymore info on this then I'll happily elaborate on it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you rely on an `id` becoming a global ... however, `window.length` has a *defined* meaning so won't be overridden by that input ... don't rely on id's becoming globals - in fact, avoid globals altogether ... at the top of that function ... `var length = document.getElementById('length')` etc

Comment: Always use a function like `document.getElementById()` to access elements by their ID.

Comment: None of the variables you are using in the if else blocks are declared, also you do not need this at all just use input type="number" instead.

Comment: @JaromandaX can you please explain that to me further and possibly give me an example? I’ve only just started learning JavaScript so some of this is pretty new to me.

Comment: load your web page ... in the console, type `window.length` ... you'll see it has a numeric value ... type `window.width` ... it is your width input element

Comment: javascript in browsers "assigns" any element with an id as a property of `window` ... so, in your case, window.area etc (that's what you access if you haven't declared area as a variable and just use area) ... however, properties of `window` that are an integral part of the window object are not overridden by id's ... such as length ... name is another one ... there are MANY such property names ... the easiest solution is to NEVER assume an id becomes a global property ... just put `var length = document.getElementById('length')` (and the same for area and width) at the top of your function